# Metric/loss for bin classification

Tags: image-classification, machine-learning-model, loss-function, metric

I have a model that has to classify inputs into one of 45 categories but those categories actually represent bins (e.g. bins 1, 2 and 3 are between 1 and 10, 11 and 20, 21 and 30 respectively). What I would like is my model to classify properly values into bins but I am not too upset if it puts 19 into bin #3 even in bin #1. What is the loss function that would measure distance from the correct category and will score the classification in neighbouring bins with weight of say 1/n where n is the distance to the correct bin.

mind you that what I am looking for is different from the top_k metric that keras has.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should redefine your task as a regression problem instead of a classification problem, because your target variable is numerical.

The performance will be much better and it will avoid the need for a questionable pseudo-regression-like measure. [Mean absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) and [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) are standard regression evaluation measures.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly how I started solving my problem but my model wouldn't converge. also considering that one of my outputs is "none of the rest" it felt like this might be a classification problem. perhaps I should be building two models

Comment: @ГеоргиКременлиев depending on the problem I can see two options: either using only regression and automatically assign any value not within the predefined range as in the "none of the rest" category; or indeed using first a binary classification model to distinguish regular cases from "none of the rest", then doing regression on the regular cases.